# Clear DataGridView datasource linked to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I'm new to Entity Framework, I have a `DataGridView` connected to Entity Framework as it shown below

```
dgvDebit.DataSource = (from daily in accountingEntities.DailyAccounts
                       join voucherdetails in accountingEntities.VoucherDetails on daily.DailyId equals voucherdetails.DailyId
                       where voucherdetails.VoucherId == keyvalue
                       group voucherdetails by daily.DailyName into dgroup
                       select new
                              {
                                  DailyName = dgroup.Key,
                                  SumOfDebit = dgroup.Sum(s => s.Debit)
                              }).ToList();
```

My question is: I want to clear `DataGridView` datasource but every thing I did has failed - please any help here?

Comment: `dgvDebit.DataSource = null;` should clear the data source - do you get an error with this? (and if so: ***what*** error do you get??)

Comment: dgvDebit.DataSource = null; its work but its clear columns too, so when i load datagridview again i loose grid format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you want to bind to an empty list of the type that you have.

**Step 1**: define a .NET type for your query result return type:

```
public class ResultDTO
{
    public string DailyName { get; set; }
    public decimal SumOfDebit { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 2**: change your "normal" query to:

```
dgvDebit.DataSource = (from daily in accountingEntities.DailyAccounts
                       join voucherdetails in accountingEntities.VoucherDetails on daily.DailyId equals voucherdetails.DailyId
                       where voucherdetails.VoucherId == keyvalue
                       group voucherdetails by daily.DailyName into dgroup
                       select new ResultDTO
                              {
                                  DailyName = dgroup.Key,
                                  SumOfDebit = dgroup.Sum(s => s.Debit)
                              }).ToList();
```

**Step 3**: if you want to "clear" the `DataGridView`, but retain the columns, you can now use:

```
dgvDebit.DataSource = new List<ResultDTO>();
```

Comment: Thank you for dedicating your time to my answer

Comment: @HusseinAl-Obaidy: you're welcome - glad I was able to help! Have a great day